# How to make Laravel filter search by the collection (name , age , data) by php code only?

Tags: laravel

How to make Laravel filter search by the collection (name , age , data) by php code only  ?

Comment: Can you reformulate your question, and provide code to show case what you want exactly to do

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you place a question try to add a minimum content: input sample, expected output sample, what did you try, research and where are you stuck. What did you try?

Answer (score 0):

the normal syntax for search any data is like below

```
$search=Search::where('name','tanvir')->where('age',22)->where('data','any')->get();
```

If you want another one then edit your question and put your controller code or what you actually want to do etc